# Why can't I get the html content of this link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with two links in each row, like this:

```
<table class="list">
    ...
    <td>
      <a href="#" id="abcdefg756">756</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>some more text</td>
    ...
</table>
```

The first link always has an ID, which starts with the same characters, followed by a random number. The second link does not have an ID. I would like to get the inner html of the first link when *either* link is clicked.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/XNqOgN

I have tried a few things using Jquery. This is what I have so far:

```
 $('.list').find("a").click(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('id') !=undefined) {
        var number = $(this).html();
        alert (number);
      } else if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined) {
        var number = $(this).prev('a').html(); 
        alert (number);
      }
    })
  });
```

This works for the first link, however it returns undefined for the second. I'm not sure why using .prev isn't working.

Any help much appreciated!

(note that I'm unable to change the HTML structure)

Comment: `.prev()` returns the previous sibling (within the parent TD) and there isn't one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a single click event, go to the parent `tr` find the link with the id starting with "abcdefg", get the text

```
$('.list tr a').click(function(){
var text = $(this).closest('tr').find('a[id^="abcdefg"]').text();
console.log(text)
});
```

the demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqKrjE?editors=1111

Comment: This returns all the text from every link with an id starting with abcdefg. I need to be specific to the one that was clicked.

Comment: @okokuro: You stated you wanted the text from the first link. That is what text() does. It does not "return the text from every link".

Comment: Your comment no longer matches your code. Like the way you snuck in that fix :)

Comment: And it's not working now... I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$('.list tr td a').first().html()` to get the first link of the table.
So, that's all you need:

```
$(function(){  
  $('.list').find("a").click(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('id') !=undefined) {//Links with id (1st column)
        var number = $(this).html();//Get clicked link
        alert (number);
      } else if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined) {//Links with no id (2nd column)
        var number = $('.list tr td a').first().html();//Get first link
        alert (number);
      }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`.prev()` returns previous adjacent sibling. If no previous sibling exists, or if the previous sibling element does not match a supplied selector, an empty jQuery object is returned.

In ur case changing `.prev()` to `.parent().prev().children()` will help.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNYMNG?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work with follow code,

```
  $(function(){

  $('.list').find("a").click(function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('id') !=undefined) {
        var number = $(this).html();
        alert (number);
      } else if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined) {
        //Little bit change here
        var number = $(this).parent().prev().find('a').html(); 
        alert (number);
      }
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: Where is `#btn` in the HTML?

Comment: sorry...forget that part.. change the line after comment only. I update the code.

Answer (score 0):

When a link is clicked, you should go to the parent "tr", then select the first link in it, like this :

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('a').eq(0);
```

That way you'll always have the first link in the row you clicked.

Comment: `closest` is always better than `parents` (which returns all ancestors)

Comment: I didn't know about `closest()`, thanks ! Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Note: Also best to use `.eq(0)` and not `[0]`. `[0]` will crash when no match is made, whereas `.eq(0)` returns a jQuery object (empty or otherwise).

Comment: Many thanks ! Is eq(0) strictly equal to .first() also ?

Comment: Yes it is the same (just shorter).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.list').find("a").click(function () {
        if (this.id == "") {

            alert(($($($($(this).parent()[0]).parent()[0]).children()[0]).children()[0]).innerHTML)
        }

    });
});
```